# Почему при записи файла файл пустой?

Tags: java, javafx

```
package sample;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import java.io.*;


public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private TextArea text_area_main;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem openfile_btn;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem savefile_btn;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        openfile_btn.setOnAction(event -> {

        });

        String output = text_area_main.getText();
        savefile_btn.setOnAction(event -> {
            FileChooser f = new FileChooser();
            f.showSaveDialog(null);
            File file = f.showSaveDialog(null);

                try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
                writer.write(output);

                }catch(IOException eq){eq.printStackTrace();}


        });
    }
}
```

файл сохраняется но он пустой. при дебаге выяснилось что output пустой. Вопрос почему? Предлагайте решение.

Comment: Потому что у вас лямда пустая xD

Answer (score 1):

после writer.write(output); закрой writer.close();

```
 @FXML
void initialize() {

    openfile_btn.setOnAction(event -> {
        output = text_area_main.getText();
        System.out.println(text_area_main.getText());
        System.out.println(output);
    });
    savefile_btn.setOnAction(event -> {
        System.out.println(output);
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write(output);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Можно использовать try с ресурсами.